# Как правильно использовать Expression Binding для полей контроллера в fxml (javaFx)?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

index.fxml:

```
<Label text="${controller.title}" />
```

Index.java:

```
private StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("Title");

//Вызывается при клике на кнопку в этом окне
public void fxOnAction() {
    title.set(title.getValue() + "-1-"); 
}

public void initialize() {
    title.set(title.getValue() + "-initialize-");
}
```

В результате при клике по кнопке значение тайтла изменяется, но изменения из initialize вообще никак не отображаются.

Хоть оно мне в таком виде и не нужно, но мне нужно понимать почему оно так не работает.

Как правильно писать такие вещи?
Где мне нужно изменять значение title, что бы оно работало?

Можете ли кинуть ссылки на информацию об этом, а то что-то не могу найти

p.s. все гетеры сеттеры есть:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty titleProperty() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title.set(title);
}
```

---

Оказалось, что у меня проект немного сломался. Пересоздал в новом проекте - и стало работать.

Comment: implement initializable есть в объявлении класса?

Comment: Да implement initializable есть

Comment: Может не тот initializable? Посмотри в импортах откуда он берется. От javaFx должен выглядеть как  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb), метода без аргументов у него нет

Comment: Тот, даже с аннотацией @Override

Comment: У вас такой код работает в обоих случаях?

Comment: Должна работать. Должна не работать, только в случае если инициализация вообще не вызывается. Потому меня смущает метод без аргументов в вопросе. Его у javaFx нет

Comment: Просто это фрагменты кода. Что бы не загромождать, убрал его здесь, а так он такой:

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

Comment: `@FXML void initialize()` есть, его вызывает `FXMLLoader` примерно на 2566 строке

Comment: А как вы контроллер указываете?

Comment: fx:controller="....Index"

Он пути правильные, так как как минимум при нажатии ctrl по Index переходит открывается он.

Comment: По-видимому это с проектом что-то не так.
(я использую idea полную версию).

Сейчас решил создать еще проект - первый раз проект как-то неправильно создался (сохранился в папку с cpp проектом...) и тоже не работало.

А потом создал нормально и заработало.